# Scrapy - response.xpath get items back seperated

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a Webpage which has multiple Blog Entries on the first page.
This is my code so far:

```
for rel in response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[*]/div/comment()[2]'):
    item = Example()
    item['title'] = rel.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[*]/div/div/input/@value').extract()
    item['link'] = rel.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[*]/div/div/span[4]/a/@href').extract()
    yield item
```

Problem is if I go with the `"*"` I get a link and a title back with all entries in it.
But I would like to have a title and a link for every single entry.
I am very new to Python and `scrapy` and don't know how to count up to get the single entries back.
The first entry starts with `"2"` and the next is `+3` till it end at 29.(2,5,8....29)

Comment: Can you provide an HTML sample of the page?

Comment: sure, the webpage is http://hd-area.org.
Want so scrape the release entries starting with <div class="beschreibung"> for each entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest more explicit XPaths. Something like should be closer to your goal:

```
for rel in response.xpath('//div[@class="beschreibung"]'):
    item['title'] = rel.xpath(".//strong[contains(text(),"Release")]/following-sibling::*[1]/@value").extract()
    item['link'] = rel.xpath('.//span[@style="display:inline;"]//a[contains(text(),"Share")]/@href').extract()
    yield item
```